# my built in camera on my MacBook Pro is not found

Tags: macbook-pro, camera, webcam

All of a sudden my computer is not finding the built in camera... I use this everyday. No FaceTime, no videorecording... nothing.

Comment: This is usually an indication of a Hardware failure.  I would try booting in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting), and also running [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: is someone exercising the parenting rights on you and has disabled it under parental control ?

Comment: I don't think so.. I am the parent and no one uses my computer that I know of in my house... I will try both of these solutions to see if it helps....

Comment: well check it anyway, there is where you can turn off the camera